# Nodejs filesystem.write position doesn't seem to be working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filesystems

I have the following problem, here's the bits of code that are of interest:

```
 var fs = require('fs');

 var fd = fs.openSync('path to file', 'a+');

 var buffer = new Buffer('Hello Text');

 fs.writeSync(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, 42)

 fs.close(fd);
```

As far as the official documentation tells me this is how the function should be called: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writesync_fd_buffer_offset_length_position

And as far as common sense and countless tried tell me postion "42" or whatever position I chose to place there means that my `writeSync` should start writting on position 42. However, without exception, it start writing on a newline exactly at the end of the file.
I've even tried using the "legacy" function `fs.writeSync(fd, 'hello string', 42, 'utf-8');` and I still get the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the documentation:

> On Linux, positional writes don't work when the file is opened in
>   append mode. The kernel ignores the position argument and always
>   appends the data to the end of the file.

Comment: Ok... Any ideas as to how I can fix this ?

Comment: I know there is a 'w' flag but that just overwrite the whole file. I could read the file, store it and then compose a new file but that seems a tad bit... slow and retarded. Is this issues something all server-side scripting languages deal with or is it specific to node ?

Comment: I don't use Linux so I can't tell you. I use Windows. Anyway I've given you the answer to your question. You have to mark this as the correct answer and open a new question: "How to open a file not in append mode via Node.js on Linux?" and to Tag #Linux and #Node.js. A wild guess: you can try to read asynchronously. You can read here about Linux different types of file opening: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html

Comment: fair enough, how do I mark it as the "correct answer" ?

Comment: On the left side, beneath the two arrows with the number between them (right not it's 0), you have a gray V sign. You click it to set the correct answer.